# Error getting contacts using plugin phonegap

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, contacts

I'm trying to get the list of phone contacts, but I get the error seguijnte:

**ContactFindOptions is not defined**

I am using this plugin: cordova plugin contacts

and for the installation I used this command:
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.contacts

Follow the step by step documentation...

```
function onSuccess(contacts) {
    alert('Found ' + contacts.length + ' contacts.');
};

function onError(contactError) {
    alert('onError!');
};

// find all contacts with 'Bob' in any name field
var options      = new ContactFindOptions();
options.filter   = "Bob";
options.multiple = true;
options.desiredFields = [navigator.contacts.fieldType.id];
var fields       = [navigator.contacts.fieldType.displayName,   navigator.contacts.fieldType.name];
navigator.contacts.find(fields, onSuccess, onError, options);
```

Any ideas???

Comment: Do you already have some other plugins installed to make sure they get installed properly? Your code obviously should work as it is the example code provided on plugin documentation.

Comment: Yes I already have another plugin installed. I'm using SqlLite and it is working perfectly. But I can not use the plugin to contacts.

Comment: I realized that if I run the console: "new ContactFindOptions ()" the object is created, but when I put the same code within the deviceOnReady it does not work.